# Masonry.js fully functioning in Firefox but not Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, coffeescript, jquery-masonry

So I'm using Dessandro's Masonry.js lib which was fully functional a short while ago, however, due to some unknown reason, it has ceased to function in both Safari and Chrome (can't speak to ie yet) but is still working fully in Firefox. If it were working in Chrome rather than Firefox I'd figure it was a css issue of some sort, possibly with transitions, but am at a bit of a loss as to where to diagnose this particular dilemma.

Masonry instantiation in coffeescript

```
window.presets = () ->
 $(".table-header").hide()
 $container = $(".employee-list")
 window.msnry = $(".employee-list").masonry(columnWidth: 100)

 showGrid msnry
 loadImages $container
```

Comment: Also I've read several other questions regarding loss of functionality in Chrome due to duplicate element id's but can't locate any duplicates in my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I suppose I feel a bit silly but it wound up being transitions. Masonry 'items' apparently will malfunction if adding transitions (no matter the type) onto boxes. I'm still at a loss as to why this would occur for Chroma and Safari but not Firefox so if anyone has any insight on the matter it would be much appreciated.